# How to implement the recursive FIR filtering of a signal with zero boundary condition?

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, convolution, finite-impulse-response, filtering

Now I have a signal $f(k)$ with $k=0,1,\ldots, N-1$, and $f(k)=0$ if $k<0$ or $k>N-1$, that is, the signal satisfies the **zero boundary condition**. Then by convolving this signal with a symmetric FIR filter $b^3(k)$, I have
$$
f_0(k) = (f*b^3)(k),
$$
in which $b^3(k)$ equals to $1/6$, $4/6$, $1/6$, for $k=-1$, $0$, $1$, respectively. Obviously, we can get
$$
f_0(-1) = f(0)/6 \\
f_0(N) = f(N-1)/6,
$$
Therefore, the length of $f_0$ is extended to $N+2$, with $f_0(k)=0$ for $k<-1$ or $k>N$.

Using $f_0$ as initial settings, I want to compute $f_i$, which is defined as
$$
f_{i+1}(k) = (f_i*[h]_{\uparrow 2^i})(k),
$$
where $i=0,1,2,3,\ldots,7$, and $[h]_{\uparrow 2^i}$ is $h(k)$ with $2^i-1$ zeros between each sample point:
$$
h(k) = 1/8, \ 1/2, \ 3/4, \ 1/2, \ 1/8, \ \text{for}\ k = -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 \\
[h]_{\uparrow 2^1} = 1/8, \ 0, \ 1/2, \ 0, \ 3/4, \ 0, \ 1/2, \ 0, 1/8, \ \text{for} \ k= -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 \\
[h]_{\uparrow 2^2} = 1/8, 0, 0, 0,1/2, 0, 0, 0,3/4, 0, 0, 0,1/2, 0, 0, 0,1/8, \ \text{for} \ k= -8,-7,-6,-5,-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8 \\
\ldots\ldots
$$

If I want to obtain values of $f_{i+1}(k)$ for $0\leq k\leq N-1$, I have to know $f_i(k)$ for $k<0$ and $k>N-1$. However, these values of $f_i(k<0)$ or $f_i(k>N-1)$ are difficult to know. Can someone help me address this issue? Is there an explicit expression for $f_i(k<0)$ or $f_i(k>N-1)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## New Answer

I think there is a much easier and more general way to tackle this.

Let's assume we have a sequence of $h[n]$ that has finite support on $[K,L]$ where $K$ is the index of the first non-zero sample and $L$ is the index of the last non-zero sample, i.e.

$$h[n] = 0, n < K \lor  n > L$$

Since that's awkward to write we will simply notate this as

$$\mathbb{S}(h) = [K,L]$$

Where $\mathbb{S}(h)= ...$ means "$h$ has finite support on $...$".

The length $N$ of the sequence is simply

$$N = L-K+1$$

Some  quick examples: The unit impulse has support on $[0,0]$ with a length of 1. A causal sequence of length $N$ has support on $[0,N-1]$, a zero phase sequence is symmetric, i.e it has support on $[-M,M]$ with a length of $2M+1$

If we convolve two sequences $h_1$ and $h_2$ the supports just sum, i.e.

$$\mathbb{S}(h_1*h_2) = [K_1+K_2,L_1+L_2]$$

The length $N_{1*2}$ of the convolution comes out to be:

$$N_{1*2} = L_1+L_2 - K_1-K_2+1 = (L_1-K_1+1) + (L_2-K_2+1) - 1 = N_1+N_2 -1$$

as would be expected.

Armed with this formalism, it's easy to calculate the support of your recursive convolution. We look at the support of the impulse responses

$$ \begin{array}{cl}
\mathbb{S}(h_0) = [-2,2] \\
\mathbb{S}(h_1) = [-4,4] \\
\mathbb{S}(h_2) = [-8,8] \\
... \\
\mathbb{S}(h_m) = [-2^{m+1},2^{m+1}] 
\end{array} $$

Let's now convolve a causal sequence $f$ with support $[0,N-1]$ with the first $M+1$ impulse response, i.e.

$$y_M = f * h_0 * h_1 * ... h_{M}$$

The support of the result will simply be the sum of the supports of all individual sequences that are being convolved, i.e we have

$$\mathbb{S}(y_M) = \left[ 0+\sum_{m=0}^M K_{hm},N-1+ \sum_{m=0}^M L_{hm}\right] = \\
\left[ -\sum_{m=0}^M 2^{m+1},N-1+ \sum_{m=0}^M 2^{m+1}\right] $$

With $\sum_{m=0}^M 2^{m+1} = 2^{m+2}-2$ we can simplify to

$$\mathbb{S}(y_M) = 
\left[ -(2^{m+2}-2), 2^{m+2} + N -3 \right] $$

This matches the result in the original answer but seems a lot easier (to me) and also doesn't make any assumptions about symmetry or alignment.

## Original Answer

Let's break this down a little.

Let's define $h_0$ as $h[n] = [1/8, \ 1/2, \ 3/4, \ 1/2, \ 1/8], n=[-2,-1,0,1,2]$. We can than define the other impulse response  in the series through upsampling as

$$h_m[n] = h_{m-1}[n] \uparrow 2 = h_0[n] \uparrow 2^m $$

The length  $L_m$ of each impulse response is

$$L_m = 2^{m+2} + 1$$

with the time index spanning from $-(L_m-1)/2 ... +(L_m-1)/2$

We can now define a set of impulse responses $g_k$ that are cumulative convolutions of the base impulse responses, i.e.

$$g_0 = h_0,  \hspace{1cm}  g_k = g_{k-1} * h_{k} $$

where $*$ is the linear convolution operator. If you convolve two sequences of length $N_1$ and $N_2$ the result will have a length of $N_1+N_2-1$ and hence the length of the cumulative impulse response will simply be

$$R_k = \sum_{i = 0}^k (L_i)-(k-1) = 2^{k+3}-3$$

Since all individual impulse response are symmetric (zero phase), so will be the cumulative impulse response, i.e. the time index will go from

$$ -(R_k-1)/2 = -(2^{k+2}-2) \leq n \leq +(R_k-1)/2 = +(2^{k+2}-2) $$

Now, finally we can convolve the cumulative impulse response with the input signal $f[k]$ which goes from $[0,N-1]$.

The length of the result, T_k, will be $T_k = R_k + N -1$ and the time span will be

$$ -(R_k-1)/2 = -(2^{k+2}-2) \leq n \leq +(R_k-1)/2 + N - 1= 2^{k+2} + N -3$$

Comment: $g_0=h_0,g_k$, $g_{k-1}*h_k$ means what ? Does that mean $g_0=h_0$ and $g_k=g_{k-1}*h_k$

Comment: yes. Good catch. Fixed

Comment: Nice update!!!!

Comment: @Hilmar In fact, all I care about are values of $y_M(k)$ for $0\leq k\leq N-1$. I want to search for a memory-efficient way to compute $y_M(k)$ in $0\leq k\leq N-1$. However, this is hindered by the expansion of the length of $y_M$.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. "Efficient" always depends on the details. Can you throw CPU at the problem? Do you have latency constraints? How accurate does it need to be ? What are rough numbers for $N$ and how many levels of recursion do you need?